# How do i set the text color when a certain element is "active"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im looking to get elements in the topnav class to change color when they are the ones selected. I've tried mimicking the code that darkens the accordion class buttons with no luck (this is how i need topnav to work, only with the text changing color and not the background)

Also need to select the active tab when in mobile view and put that header at the top as currently it is constantly showing purchasing online even if i'm in another tab.

Thanks in advance!

```css
<style>
body {margin:0;}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}

.topnav a {
  float: none;
  display:inline-flex;
  text-align:center;
  
  color: #4ca0d5; /* THIS WONT CHANGE */
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: big caslon;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none; 
}

.topnav a:hover {
  color: #24526f;
}


.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

/* for screens over 600px wide */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
 
  }
}

/* for screens under 600px wide */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position:absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: inherit;
    display:block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
  }

}

/* deals with each tab that pops up when clicking header buttons */

.tabcontent {
    color: black;
    display: none;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    text
}

/* deals with internal accordion buttons in the body */ 

button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin: 0px 15px 0px 0px

}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 25px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

</style>
```

```html
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav" align="center" >
  <a href="#purchasingonline" onclick="openFAQ('Purchasing-Online', this, 'white')" id="defaultOpen">Purchasing Online</a>
  <a href="#productinformation" onclick="openFAQ('productinformation', this, '#white')">Product Information</a>
  <a href="#payment" onclick="openFAQ('payment', this, '#white')">Payment</a>
  <a href="#shipping" onclick="openFAQ('shipping', this, 'white')">Shipping & Delivery</a>
  <a href="#returns" onclick="openFAQ('returns', this, 'white')">Returns</a>
  <a href="#contactus" onclick="openFAQ('contactus', this, 'white')">Contact us</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>

<!--BODY START-->

<div id="Purchasing-Online" class="tabcontent">
   <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
  <div class="panel">
     <p>text goes here</p>
  </div><br>
  
 <button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
  <div class="panel">
     <p>text goes here</p>
  </div><br>
  
 <button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
  <div class="panel">
     <p>text goes here</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="productinformation" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="payment" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<div id="shipping" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Oslo</h3>
  <p>Oslo is the capital of Norway.</p>
</div>

<div id="returns" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<div id="contactus" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Oslo</h3>
  <p>Oslo is the capital of Norway.</p>
</div>


<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}
</script>

<script>
function openFAQ(faqPanel,elmnt,color) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
    document.getElementById(faqPanel).style.display = "block";
    elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>

<!--BODY END-->

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: some of your elements have duplicated "id" attribute. It is not allowed.

Comment: You will please watch your language on SO

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Multiple same name IDs and the align attribute is obsolete.

Comment: which ones? i'm not throwing up any errors?

Comment: <a id="11" href="#purchasingonline" onclick="openFAQ('Purchasing-Online', this, 'white')" id="defaultOpen"> You have two ids here. (I said it wrong in my other comment)

Comment: @Rob got them sorted, the numbered tags were obsolete anyway. thanks for the revisions of my angry comments :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQuery then the following code will helps you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".topnav > a").click(function(event) {
            $(".topnav > a").css('color','black');
            $(this).css('color','red');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks for your help, i'll be sure to look into jquery more often now!

Answer (score 0):

**:active** is a pseudoclass, that is indicates a state of element. But **.active** is a class, so you can just add this class to element that has been clicked and became active. Then, when you click to other element, you need to remove **.active** class from previously active element and add it to current, like this:

```
$('.topnav > a').click(function() {
  // check if current element doesn't active
  if(!$(this).hasClass('.active')) {

    // then remove ".active" class from all **.topnav > a** elements
    $('.topnav > a.active').removeClass('active');

    // and add ".active" class to clicked element
    $(this).addClass('active');
  } else {
    return false;
  }
```

you can just change color of .active button:

```
.topnav > a.active {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: This would work but I need it to stay, in your case red, after the click is released. then when the next element is clicked the new one changes color and the previous element goes back to the base color

Answer (score 0):

```
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

In javascript, you can remove class named 'active' from all the tab, then add class 'active' to which you want to change

Comment: can i add this into the openFAQ function?